# How to fetch entities without their association mapping in Doctrine 2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

If you have a set of association mapped entities in Doctrine, sometimes you might want to retrieve those entities without its mapped associations being fetched and slowing the query down.

For example I have a set of entities which are association mapped in a chain of linked database tables. They are all OnetoMany associations and act as a hierarchy of prices in matrices on product pages. They can be represented as so:

```
SitePage->SiteMatrix->SiteItems->SiteItemPrices.
```

The associated mapping works perfectly, and when I use the findBy method to get the root SitePage object it contains arrays which represent the mapped entities down the chain. In other words the SitePage object contains all matrices, which contains all items which contains all prices. So far so good.

My problem is that every time I get a list of pages on my site, doctrine is walking the entire association mapping tree and returning me with the entire datatabase which is very slow. Sometime I want to just get my SitePage entity by ID and not contain all the mapped associations.

I have looked into lazy and extra lazy loading of associations but they only seem to affect certain functions, and not findBy etc. The official documentation is far from helpful:
http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html

Other similar questions on Stack Overflow have gone unanswered:
[Doctrine 2 Association Mapping Overhead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811570/doctrine-2-association-mapping-overhead)

Is there an easy way to fetch an entity without its mapped associations? The easiest way I can see currently is to create two entities for each database table, one with association mapping and one without for use in the separate situations where they are required. It seems odd to me that you cannot simply fetch an entity and specify whether you want to link to it to other entities or fetch it by itself.

Thanks for any information on the subject.

Comment: Doctrine should lazy load associations by default. It sounds like all your associations are set to eager loading. Could you add the code for two entities with their association mapping to rule out any association problems?

Comment: Thankyou for your response, but this problem is now over a year old. It turned out that I was using a serializer to serialize my entities into arrays, and it was this serializer that was calling every getter function down the association mapping tree. Once I learned about exclusions, max depth, and groups functionality within the JMS Serializer bundle it all became clear and I was able to wield the association with much more control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMSSerializer exclusion strategies can help you.

First, exclude all properties by default :

```
// ...

use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @JMS\ExclusionPolicy("all")
 */
class Foo
```

Then, choose to exclude or expose your properties :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 * @JMS\Expose
 */
protected $name;
```

Also, for your associations, you can use the `MaxDepth` to restrict the associated entries of your results. Example :

```
// Entity
/** @MaxDepth(1) */
private $selfAssociatedEntries;

// Controller
use JMS\Serializer\SerializationContext;

$serializer->serialize($data, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->enableMaxDepthChecks());
```

Like this, your entity will contains the `$selfAssociatedEntries` serialised, but the `$selfAssociatedEntries` doesn't have the `$selfAssociationEntries` property.
The serialisation is restricted to the first parent object.

`Groups` are a powerful feature that allows you to expose properties for some actions and exclude them for another :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true, unique=false)
 * @JMS\Groups({"default"}) // Set the group to expose the property
 */
protected $name;
```

In your controller, set the group used for serialisation :

```
// Property 'name' is exposed
$serializer->serialize($data, 'json', SerializationContext::create()->setGroups(array('default')));
```

For more informations, look at [Exclusion Strategies](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies) chapter of the documentation.

Comment: Thankyou very much for explaining this concept thoroughly. Using JMSSerializer exclusion strategies makes doctrine association mapping a very powerful tool. Official Docs for ref - http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/cookbook/exclusion_strategies

Comment: You're welcome , thank you for your patience. If you have a better explanation of maxDeprh, don't hesitate  to say me and I'll improve mine.

Comment: This is all good, but does this still affects the underlying query?, this is presentation, the query still needs to happen right ?

Comment: Does it affects the actual queries to db in case I excluded an associated entity?

Comment: I can't be sure about what happen from the query side, as I didn't look deeper enough in the JMS serializer code. My guess is that the treatment is done after the query, so it doesn't affect it at all, but again I'm not sure.

Comment: I would GUESS that the query is affected as the whole operation is enormously sped up when excluding the mappings by group.