# How to limit OneToMany/ManyToOne associations depth/loop in Doctrine2?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, associations, model-associations

I've 3 doctrine entities. One is `User`, second is `Product` and third is `ProductUsers`.

So, `User` have `OneToMany` association with `ProductUsers` and the same `Product` have OneToMany association with `ProductUsers`. `ProductUsers` has `ManyToOne` association with both `User` and `Product`.  Like so:

```
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var ProductUsers
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductUsers", mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $productUsers;
}

class ProductUsers
{
    /**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="productUsers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    private $product;

    /**
     * @var User
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="productUsers")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")
     */
    private $user;

    // extra fields ...
}

class User
{
    /**
     * @var ProductUsers
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductUsers", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $productUsers;
}
```

A user can use multiple products and a product can have multiple users. `ProductUsers` has some extra info about the relation other than just the relation.

The problem is when I fetch one `User` object it comes with associated `ProductUsers` and it's associated `Product`. Not only that but the `Product` also comes with all it's associated `ProductUsers` and it's respective `User` objects which is quite an overhead.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11811570/doctrine-2-association-mapping-overhead) question closely relates to my problem.

I'm looking to limit that at doctrine level just like what JMSSerializerBundle `MaxDepth` does. Is there a way to limit such overhead in doctrine?

Comment: This is how Doctrine works. The collection you get should be lazy collections, ie, only when you access the underlying data the actual data is fetched from DB. By Default when fetching a User only the SELECT * FROM users query will run. To fetch records at once (not lazy) you need to join them in an ORM Query Select: $qb->select('u', 'up')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced this issue long time back. I tried `lazy loading`. Which didn't work as expected and that was not a proper solution to my issue. So I did some R&D and came up with a solution that I don't need a `bidirectional` relationship from `Product` to `ProductUsers`.

I can manage same relationship with `unidirectional` handling only from `ProductUsers` side. You will need `One-To-Many` Association when you need a `cascade-persist` or similar feature. I wrote a [small blog](http://jdjeetonweb.blogspot.in/2014/12/doctrine-mapping-orm-with-database-dal.html) regarding this as well.

So, for your solution, just have `Many-To-One` association from `ProductUsers` with both `Product` and `User` entity. You will not need any change in your database association.

And when you need Products associated for a single user, you can always save a `Querybuilder` in Repository to use when you need associated data.

It will save a lot of performance. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jeet! Currently I'm solving the issue with `DQL` to fetch the only needed. I also need `OneToMany` in case I need list of product users or vice-versa but that is making the problem here so custom queries are the way to go. `OneToMany` is almost useless :(